# Associative array in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add users to my servers using Ansible.  Each user have a different encrypted password.

I have something like that:

```
vars:
  users:
    - myuser1
    - myuser2
  password: encryptedpasswordhere

tasks:
  - name: Creating users
    user: name={{ item }} password={{ password }} groups=sudo,adm shell=/bin/bash
    with_items: users
```

This work great, but all users have the same password.

I'm looking to make an associative array.  In PHP I would do that:

```
$users = array('user'=>'myuser1', 'password'=>'encryptedpass1',
               'user'=>'myuser2', 'password'=>'encryptedpass2',
               );
```

There is a way to do that in an Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes

```
---
users:
  alice:
    name: Alice Appleworth
    telephone: 123-456-7890
  bob:
    name: Bob Bananarama
    telephone: 987-654-3210
```

and

```
tasks:
  - name: Print phone records
    debug: msg="User {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.name }} ({{ item.value.telephone }})"
    with_dict: users
```

Comment: @Francis As a fellow PHP dev I wasn't aware that most other languages call our "associative arrays" "hashes". Helps with Googling!

Comment: @ceejayoz "hash" or "dict".